# Exclude Items from a Specific category in MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The following code will get all the latest items from all the categories present in my database. I want to hide all items from a specific category so it doesn't show items from that specific category, but still shows items from other categories.

```
$query="
SELECT t1 . *,
DATEDIFF( t1.date_added, '$curDate' ) as remaining,
at.auctions_type_name
FROM wp_mam_auctions AS t1
INNER JOIN wp_mam_auction_type AS at ON at.auctions_type_id = t1.auction_type_id
WHERE  t1.auction_status_id = '1' AND t1.sold='0'
AND DATEDIFF( t1.date_added, '$curDate' ) <= '0'
AND DATEDIFF( t1.date_added, '$curDate' ) >= '-$new_listing_days'
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , '$curDate', t1.date_expiry ) >'0'
ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT $from1, $max_results1
";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a where clause and say to not show items of those category. Like

```
 WHERE category!="blah"
```